# How to calculate percentile(Var) for different quartile values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, percentile

Below is my main python code. From here i calling method called varmethod. And passing passing multiple quartile values in the form of array.

```py
CI = [60,70,80,90.5]
cl_obj.varmethod(CI,simulation)
```

This is my varmethod:

```py
def varmethod(self,CI,simulationDf):
    total = simulationDf['Grand Total'].sum() 
    print(total)
    percentiles = np.percentile(total, CI)
    print(percentiles)
    df = pd.DataFrame(CI,columns=['CI'])
    df['Var'] = percentiles
    print(df)
```

whenever I run it shows result like below:

```py
4.820088072712291e+72
[4.82008807e+72 4.82008807e+72 4.82008807e+72 4.82008807e+72]
         CI           Var
    0  60.0  4.820088e+72
    1  70.0  4.820088e+72
    2  80.0  4.820088e+72
    3  90.5  4.820088e+72
```

It not calculate percentile(Var) properly.

Answer (score 0):

Percentile function runs on an array. The 50% percentile of an array of one element is the element itself.
So either you should not `sum()` your `Grand Total` column or you just want to multiply the ouput of the sum() by the given decimals such as `0.6 0.7 0.8 .....`

I believe the right way is `percentiles = np.percentile(total, simulationDf['Grand Total'].values)`

In any case I don't know what kind of VaR you are calculating but a number with power of 10^72 seems to be way too big

Comment: here total grand total is nothing but sum of simulation total.

Comment: yeah so then you want to apply your percentiles directly to your loss simulation in order to calculate the VaR

Comment: i feel like you haven't understood how VaR is working

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: Here I just need to calculate percentile for given quartiles.

Comment: VaR is obtaining the minimum value you will lose in case of an event among the XX% most extreme. A quartile is applied to an array of value, otherwise it is just a percentage

Comment: I'm not gonna do it for you. I explained the steps to you, now you need to think and work by yourslef